# supabase "TypeError: fetch failed" using next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase

I am trying to make a request to nextjs route handler where I am using supabase database to retreive some rows from a particular database table. The table exist and it is already filled with rows. Below is the code where I am facing above bug.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { supabase } from "../../utils/db"; // --> This piece of line works and it doesn't seem to have any issue because I use this utility function throughout my application.

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
let { data, error } = await supabase.from('tableName') // ---> tableName does exist and it also is filled with rows.
.select(`
    id,
    created_at,
    date,
    position,
    description,
    tags,
    apply_url,
    slug,
    job_type,
    approved,
    customer_deactivation,
    featured,
    dashboard_url,
    review_id,
    category_name,
    email,
    global_talent,
    hq,
    website,
    meta_description,
    location,
    visa_sponsorship,
    company (id, company_name, company_website, company_description, company_email, company_logo)
  `);

  if (error) {
    console.info("IF: ", { error });
    return res.json({ message: error.message});
  }
}
```

Above condition gets true every time I make a request to nextjs route. Below is the complete error I am getting.

```
IF:  {
  error: {
    message: 'TypeError: fetch failed',
    details: 'TypeError: fetch failed\n' +
      '    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11600:11)\n' +
      '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n' +
      '    at async handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/jobs.ts:16:48)',
    hint: '',
    code: ''
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of next do you use?

Comment: How did you set up the relationship of tableName and company table?

Comment: @dim_dev version 13.5.3.

Comment: @grigor I used supabase user interface for relationships using foreign key relation.

Comment: I am facing this exact issue as well. i am unable to successfully call supabase from my api route, been stuck on this for weeks. Im hoping the team at vercel will get back to my issue i post on their repo.

Comment: Because API routes in general are stateless, you need to create supabase client on each request (createRouteHandlerClient). Here is the docs link: supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs#server-side or here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/creating-a-client?environment=route-handler#creating-a-client

Comment: you should create a reproducible code base.